# Try to use SES Services with Soto SDK and Vapor 4 to send email with my own route

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, vapor

I want to use SES Services with Vapor 4 to send an Email with my own route.

I follow step by step the recommendation in Soto Doc to use Vapor 4.

But I got this error :
AsyncHTTPClient/HTTPClient.swift:591: Precondition failed: Provided EventLoop must be part of clients EventLoopGroup.

Some one can give me some explanations or explain how can I implement Soto SES with Vapor.

Thanks :)

I follow the Soto SDK documentation to implement SES Services but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

This issue lacks some code samples of how you set it up, but I'm assuming the following:

```swift
let awsClient = AWSClient(
    credentialProvider: .static(accessKeyId: myAccessKeyId, secretAccessKey: mySecretAccessKey),
    httpClientProvider: .createNew
)
```

You can access `application.http.client.shared` to use Vapor's instance of `AsyncHTTPClient` instead as such:

```swift
let awsClient = AWSClient(
    credentialProvider: .static(accessKeyId: myAccessKeyId, secretAccessKey: mySecretAccessKey),
    httpClientProvider: .shared(application.http.client.shared)
)
```

Vapor's `req.eventLoop` is part of an EventLoopGroup (multiple threads with EventLoops), and gets one of those threads assigned to it.

If you then call `aws.ses.sendEmail(sendEmailRequest, on: req.eventLoop)`, that `on:` parameter **must** be an EventLoop that is part of a group used for the AsyncHTTPClient. If you use `.createNew` to create a new HTTPClient, it'll create a separate EventLoopGroup from Vapor's. So your request will not use a valid thread for AsyncHTTPClient. While you can still use the AsyncHTTPClient's EventLoop for the request, it's definitely recommended to re-use the AsyncHTTPClient Vapor has here.

Comment: Oh My god ! 

Thanks ! 

Yes I create an other EventLoop that's why I got this problem. 
Now I use .share instead of .createNew

Thanks !